# learning sql creating table gives error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am learning to use phpmyadmin and there is a database tshirtshop which has a table department now I want to create a category table but the sql in phpmyadmin is giving me error following is SQL query

```
CREATE TABLE 'category' ( 
'category_id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
'department_id' INT NOT NULL, 
'name' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
'description' VARCHAR(1000), 
PRIMARY KEY ('category_id'), 
KEY 'idx_category_department_id' ('department_id') 
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

and following is the error
 `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
''category' ( 'category_id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'department_id' INT NOT ' at line 1`

what should I do to eliminate the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct query is

```
CREATE TABLE `category` ( 
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  department_id INT NOT NULL, 
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  description VARCHAR(1000), 
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`), 
  KEY `idx_category_department_id` (`department_id`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

you cannot use single quote to enclose field name or table name, either use tilt ` or don't use anything. in my query I try to use both just to show you.

Answer (score 1):

Try change the escape char from ' to ` . MySQL thinks that youre object names are strings.

```
CREATE TABLE `category` ( 
`category_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`department_id` INT NOT NULL, 
`name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
`description` VARCHAR(1000), 
PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`), 
KEY `idx_category_department_id` (`department_id`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```